# Converting epoch time with milliseconds to datetime

Tags: python, ruby, datetime, epoch

I have used a ruby script to convert iso time stamp to epoch, the files that I am parsing has following time stamp structure:

```
2009-03-08T00:27:31.807
```

Since I want to keep milliseconds I used following ruby code to convert it to epoch time:

```
irb(main):010:0> DateTime.parse('2009-03-08T00:27:31.807').strftime("%Q")
=> "1236472051807"
```

But In python I tried following:

```
import time 
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1236472051807))
```

But I don't get the original time date time back,

```
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1236472051807))
'41152-03-29 02:50:07'
>>>
```

I wonder is it related to how I am formatting?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = 1236472051807 / 1000.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
'2009-03-08 09:27:31.807000'
```

`%f` directive is only supported by [`datetime.datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime), not by [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

**UPDATE** Alternative using [`%`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> import time
>>> s, ms = divmod(1236472051807, 1000)  # (1236472051, 807)
>>> '%s.%03d' % (time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)), ms)
'2009-03-08 00:27:31.807'
>>> '{}.{:03d}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(s)), ms)
'2009-03-08 00:27:31.807'
```

Comment: yeah I was gonna suggest this ... but meh good answer(+1 for preserving the milliseconds in the display :))

Comment: Please note @falsetru first answer divide by floating point `1000.0` thus maintaining the milliseconds in the datetime.

Comment: Note: `fromtimestamp` expects an int or a float. If you pass it a Decimal; its behaviour depends on your python version. Some python versions (<= 3.5?) will convert to a float and work as expected. While python 3.8 issues a warning and **converts to an int**, discarding any milliseconds your input may have provided.

Answer (score 24):

those are miliseconds, just divide them by 1000, since gmtime expects seconds ...

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(1236472051807/1000.0))
```

Comment: I see but I ll be loosing the milliseconds right..?

Comment: yes ...  I think you can keep them by doing `timestamp/1000.0`  which will pass them in as a decimal ... (although Im not sure if you can retrieve them)

Comment: is there an equivalent to gmtime that takes micro or milliseconds as an input?

Comment: `seconds == milliseconds/1000` ... if you put this in a function you will have a gmtime that accepts milliseconds ... micro seconds you just divide by 10^6

Answer (score 3):

I'm a pendulum fan... so...

```py
import pendulum
pendulum.from_timestamp(1236472051807/1000.0,tz='America/Toronto')
```

outputs:

> `DateTime(2019, 12, 20, 10, 55, 10, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Toronto'))`

For all the searches looking for `internalDate` for the Gmail API... the above is what works for me and is more accurate than the `Date` header.