# JSON Imported Unix Timestamps cannot be formatted

Tags: python, json, datetime, matplotlib

I have a JSON file full of unix timestamps in string form. I am trying to convert these timestamps to human readable times to then display in matplotlib.pyplot.

Upon converting the timestamps I am getting the error:

> ValueError: unconverted data remains: .1806107

How can I convert my dates to a human readable form `YY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`?

```
contents = json.loads(open("foo.json").read()) 
dates = [ ticker['date'] for ticker in contents ]
data = [ ticker['last'] for ticker in contents ]

# Example of array contents
#dates = [1497918349.3060017, 1497918352.9935713, 1497918358.8218484, 1497918364.0406654, 1497918368.9628277]
#data = [1,2,3,4,5]

# Error occurs here
dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(str(date),'%Y%m%d%H%M') for date in dates]

# Also tried the following but I get the error:
# TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
dates=[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(date) for date in dates]

plt.plot(dates, data, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = [1497918349.3060017, 1497918352.9935713, 1497918358.8218484, 1497918364.0406654, 1497918368.9628277]

dates = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(d).strftime('%F %T') for d in dates]

dates
['2017-06-20 00:25:49',
 '2017-06-20 00:25:52',
 '2017-06-20 00:25:58',
 '2017-06-20 00:26:04',
 '2017-06-20 00:26:08']
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain in one or two sentences why this code works but OP's code doesn't. This would make this answer useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your

```
dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(str(date),'%Y%m%d%H%M') for date in dates]
```

to

```
dates=[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(date).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') for date in dates]
```

all will be fine.

E.g.:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime as dt

dates = [1497918349.3060017, 1497918352.9935713, 1497918358.8218484, 1497918364.0406654, 1497918368.9628277]

# Error used to occur here
#dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(str(date),'%Y%m%d%H%M') for date in dates]
dates=[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(date).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') for date in dates]

print(dates)
```

gives:

```
['201706200325', '201706200325', '201706200325', '201706200326', '201706200326']
```

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787689/1656850) for elaboration.