# convert unix timestamp in milliseconds to UTC time & date formatting python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, unix-timestamp

I have a list of Unix timestamps that I want to convert into UTC time:

```
times = [..., "1371605102000", "1375245962000", ...]
```

However, these times are in milliseconds. I tried this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal

unix_timestamp = float("1371605102000")
local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp, local_timezone)

print(local_time.strftime("%B %d %Y"))
```

But it threw up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    local_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_timestamp, local_timezone)
ValueError: year 45434 is out of range
```

I feel like it has to do with the fact that the timestamp is in milliseconds, but I'm not entirely sure.

Other than that, I was also wondering if there was a way to format the dates to something like this:

```
...
Jan 04, 2017
Oct 27, 2016
...
```

Rather than this:

```
...
January 4, 2017
October 27, 2016
....
```

Comment: @StephenRauch this is the exact opposite of that..

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai, How about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787496/converting-epoch-time-with-milliseconds-to-datetime ?

Comment: To OP, why can't you divide by 1000, note the remainder, and then convert like you do above?

Comment: @StephenRauch yes better