# How to convert epoch time to time

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch

I have epoch time like this `1488445200000`
and I need to convert it to datetime variable. I tried

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1488445200000 // 3600)
dt
```

I got

```
datetime.datetime(1983, 2, 7, 10, 10)
```

but the result does not seem to be right (the right one should be  March 2, 2017 10:00:00 AM GMT+01:00)... what shall I do?

And what if what is I need to do is not just for one value 1488445200000 but for a column in a dataframe. Do I have to loop? Or is there a matrix operation?

Comment: Use `datetime.fromtimestamp(1488445200000 / 1000)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787496/converting-epoch-time-with-milliseconds-to-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting epoch time with milliseconds to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787496/converting-epoch-time-with-milliseconds-to-datetime)

Comment: https://codeofmatt.com/2017/10/05/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Answer (score 2):

Your timestamp is in milliseconds and datetime expects seconds. Divide by 1000 and it works:

```
$ python3 
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 29 2018, 20:13:13) 
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1488445200000 // 1000)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 2, 10, 0)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Just one more question. What is I need to do this for a column in a dataframe. Do I have to loop? Or is there a matrix operation?

Comment: I don't know anything about dataframes. Looping is probably the easiest, but you may also be able to apply the fromtimestamp function using something like: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html#pandas.DataFrame.agg

Comment: @MattJohnson I didn't?

Comment: @MattJohnson Ah, makes sense. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Use `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = int(1488445200000//1000)
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```